# Notepad++ NppFTP won't connect over SFTP

Tags: notepad++, sftp

I have used the same SFTP profile in notepad++/NppFTP for a year now, but as of yesterday it won't connect to my site, it pops the error message:

> [SFTP] Connection failed : kex error : no match for method kex algos:
>   server [diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256], client
>   [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]

I have tried WinSCP and SFTP works there without issues.

Also tried installing notepad++ on another machine and trying from there. Same issue. It won't even ask if I trust the server as it always does when connecting for the first time from a new machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can verify that I am also getting this error. It has been annoying me all this week. I have not changed any settings. I assume it has something to do with a Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and after giving an hour I found a solution.

It's happen after windows get upgraded.

Here is the solution:

Open Windows firewall, go to Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall > Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall (Windows Defender Firewall > Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall

See the below screenshot, you just need to allow the private and public access

[image]

if you are facing for FileZilla then repeat the same thing. It should work

Comment: I'm running Notepad++ on Wine Linux how should  allowed it , BTW ftp connection works well